# How to enable lost mode on devices managed my Meraki Dashboard using the API

Tags: python, api, mdm, meraki-api

this is my first post. I'm sorry if I miss something.

I am a developer tasked to create an automatic program that will enable lost mode on devices as well as ping them. The Meraki API is able to ping devices such as switches but not System Manager devices like iPods. Has anyone gotten this to work either using the Meraki python module or the API? I have looked everywhere and cant find anything along those lines.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://documentation.meraki.com/SM/Monitoring_and_Reporting/Using_Lost_Mode_to_Recover_Missing_iOS_Devices

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Although that may be helpful to some, I am looking to do that exact same thing with the Meraki API